# Can't use vector::insert "no instance of overloaded function..."

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, compiler-errors

```
class largeNum
{

public:
     std::vector<int>& getValue();

private:
    std::vector<int> value;
};
```

This is the base class I'm using with the getValue() method.

```
std::vector<int>& largeNum::getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

The error now appears trying to insert values in vectors:

```
largeNum operator+(largeNum& summand1, largeNum& summand2) {
    largeNum returnNum;
    int size = 0;
    //adapts the smaller vektor to the larger vektor by resizing him and reversing him so 1 turns into 00...01
    if (summand1.getValue().size() > summand2.getValue().size()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (summand1.getValue().size() - summand2.getValue().size()); i++) {
            //error happens here
            summand2.getValue().insert(0, 0);
        }
    }
[...]
```

Interestingly I can use all methods apart from `vector::insert` and `vector::erase`.

It gives me an error saying I would need to pass it two ints, which I am doing.

> no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::insert [with _Ty=int, _Alloc=std::allocator<int>]" matches the argument list

Comment: Insert doesn't take two ints as its parameters. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Comment: The loop, the `operator+`, the function call to `getValue()`.. all irrelevant. Please make a [MCVE] next time so that your question is re-usable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the [overloads of `vector<T>::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) takes position. They all take an iterator, so you need to call `begin` on the vector to get the insertion position.

To avoid calling `summand1.getValue()` twice, store the result in a reference:

```
std::vector<int> &tmp = summand1.getValue();
tmp.insert(tmp.begin(), 0);
```

Comment: Plus one although I'm sad to see you're a right-aligned-asterisks/ampersands guy ;( *sniff*

Comment: @BoundaryImposition An unfortunate feature of C/C++ syntax, which lets us declare objects of many different types in a single declaration (e.g. `int x, *y, **z`) forced me into the camp of right-aligners. I wish C++ designers did something about it back in the early days of the new language, but now it's too late to do anything about it.

Comment: I still don't really understand why right-aligners cling to that one extreme edge case (in a syntactical feature we shouldn't even be using anyway), in the face of so many more important considerations!

Comment: Plus 1 for right &/* alignment :) Practical and personally, more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition. Friendly question and out of curiosity, what important considerations are you referring to?

Comment: @user54264611634646244: Ready made response :) http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: An oft-heard argument for right-alignment is that the grammar is defined in right-aligned terms, but nobody's ever been able to explain to me why that actually matters. I mean, if you're declaring super-complex nested C-like types, you have bigger problems anyway ^_^

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I get your point. You should get involved in the C++20 standard and enforce this :)

Comment: @user54264611634646244: Nah, like dasblinkenlight said, it's too late now

Answer (score 1):

Your first parameter to `insert()` must be an iterator, not an `int`.

Furthermore, having a public member function returning a reference to a private member is a bad smell since you are in fact breaking encapsulation.

Thus my suggestion is to use the pattern "tell, don't ask":

```
class largeNum
{

public:
     void insertFront(int value);  // implemented via value.insert() and value.begin()

private:
    std::vector<int> value;
};
```